# Why would I ever use a traditional array rather than an ArrayList object?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The only reason I can think of is that regular arrays use less memory (though it's probably negligible) and can store primitives. Even then, you can just use wrapper classes.

Comment: you can store primitives in an ArrayList.

Comment: @clcto: Yes you can, but when you try to use `ArrayList.get(someDouble)` it won't work unless you wrap it because it's an object.

Comment: Aside from the various possible slowdowns, the very fact that ArrayList is backed by an array could be suggestive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regular arrays *do* use less memory, for starters, because they are created at the exact size needed, whereas an ArrayList can be wasting as much as half of its capacity, which is not negligible if the ArrayList is big enough.

Also, the access to the elements in an array is faster, as it doesn't require the call of `get()` and similar methods: it's a direct memory access.

And last but not least, an array is created of the exact, correct type (even primitive types, which can't be stored directly into an ArrayList), whereas an ArrayList is always an `Object[]` under the hood, and there will be a performance penalty for the extra cast required to extract each element.

Comment: +1 Apart from all that, you are required to use arrays when working with native codes.

Comment: One comment on get(): ArrayList.get() translates to direct memory access as well (but yes, you do get the method call penalty)

Comment: @MrBackend _everything_ eventually translates to memory accesses :) but my point holds, there's _at least_ an additional method call involved, probably more if we take into account the abstract classes in ArrayList's hierarchy. Some of those calls will get optimized away when the JIT compiler kicks-in ... a lot of hassle, compared to a simple `array[index]` call.

Answer (score 4):

1. It uses less space
2. It's faster
3. It can store primitives
4. It enforces a defined size, which helps with error finding

Comment: While an array can be theoretically faster, generally I think the differences will be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the two already good answers that cover functional aspects, I think readability should not be forgotten.

If you have a more-than-one-dimensional array of String, say three, you don't have to write

```
List<List<List<String>>> stringCube = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>;
// all the initialization
```

when you can do

```
String[][][] stringCube = new String[2][2][2];
```

or even

```
String[][][] stringCube = {{{"000"},{"001"}},
                           {{"010"},{"011"}},
                           {{"100"},{"101"}},
                           {{"110"},{"111"}}};
```

Which you can't do this short when using an (Array)List.

Answer (score 1):

Speed.  Object creation and method calls are expensive.  If you really need to optimize (games for example), primitive data structures can help.

Here's a little program to illustrate the speed difference.  Filling the primitive array with 1 million ints takes approx 5 millis on my system.  Filling the object list takes approx 150 millis.

```
static int SIZE = 1000000;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] myInts = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        myInts[i] = i;
    }
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
        myList.add( i );
    }
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "primitive array time: " + (t1-t0) );
    System.out.println( "object list time: " + (t2-t1) );
}
```